# Media Queries not working properly in Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, css, media-queries

I've been working on a mobile first website, and have found that my media queries aren't working properly in Chrome for iOS. It seems that no matter what size device I use (iPhone, iPad) and what orientation I view it at, the page is showing a hybrid version of the baseline (mobile) styles and the "above 481px" styles. I uploaded a small gallery of screenshots (with descriptions) to illustrate this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL0Vk.jpg

You can see the page live at http://dev.thesmackpack.com. The CSS is unminified in case there's anything you can learn by poking around in there. The media queries have worked properly in every other browser I've tested them in, only Chrome for iOS is giving me these problems.

EDIT: It seems to be working fine on some other devices I found to test on. But I can't make it UN-break on my iPhone and iPad and those are the devices I'm developing the site on so the problem is still a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem seems to have magically resolved itself. I think it may be somehow related to Chrome's "Request Desktop Site" feature but I'm not positive. Wish I had some better advice for future problem-havers.

Comment: Even in 2023 it is a good tip to force chrome to refresh the cache of a site, works even better than clear browser data in the menu.

Answer (score 5):

It does look like chrome just won't let go of it's cache. I tried deleting cache, history, etc. No affect. Reinstalled the app and all the correct styles loaded. Looks like they got some bugs to fix.

Comment: We were experiencing a CSS issue on a newly redesigned site.  After much troubleshooting and many attempts to clear cache on multiple phones (iOS + Chrome).  Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome on the phone solved fixed the issue.

iOS 8.13, Chrome 40.0.2214.69

Answer (score 4):

Try separating your viewport meta with semi-colons

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">`

If that fails you might need to restrict zooming

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to help. But I will separate the viewport meta in the future just in case...

Comment: As a TOTAL aside, I'm not sure why it's "acceptable" from a usability standpoint (I've seen maximum-scale=1 in a lot of code) to restrict zooming on the page. There's a lot of people who need to zoom in on things to see them properly.

Comment: I think the main reason it's there is to stop users zooming out on mobile sites. Completely agreed with the whole usability thing though.

Comment: After experiencing the same issue (media queries not working), switching the comma after `device-width` to a semicolon solved the problem.

Comment: According to some additional research, proper syntax is comma, not semi-colon. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250910/viewport-argument-value-device-width-for-key-width-is-invalid-and-has-been

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I found my style sheets were half breaking in Chrome iOS (but working fine on every other browser and device I tried, media queries included) until I made the sylesheet link in my head tag a full url - "http://www.directory/style.css", as opposed to just a relative file path ("/style.css", or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If I run into this again I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. @Nick Simpson-Deeks answer worked for me (full URL path to stylesheet). What also worked was putting the media queries in a separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the @media css in a separate file. Mobile chrome caches like crazy and the reason why it looked like you fixed it by moving it to a different sheet, is because chrome thought it was new and hadn't cached it yet.

Answer (score 0):

make sure if You didn't copypaste too many `@media` words e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px), @media screen and (max-device-width: 1200px), @media screen and (max-height: 720px), @media screen and (max-device-height: 720px){
  ...
}
```

there should be only one `@media` in the beginning! This is very common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ! **Make sure your browser showing a page on a 100% withour any zoom.** If its zoomed it will mess up all the mediaqueries calculations :)