# Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting this error in JavaScript:

> Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Well, you seem to have a `;` in your `device-width;` value, perhaps you need to remove that because it's "not a separator in viewport values" as the error clearly states? If that doesn't fix it, then put the code into your question that's setting the viewport width.

Comment: i dont have any device-width in my page.... i didnt find the word "viewport" word in my application ....

Comment: Well, if you're getting this error from JavaScript, there should be other information in the console where the error is, such as the file and line number that caused it. We need more information than what you've given if we're to help you at all.

Comment: actually is not an error its a warning!!! which is a totally different thing... but you can correct it with Dismas Pante answer

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I had this same error. Oddly, it's quite simple to fix. Just change the semicolons for commas, like in:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```